# Inverse probability matrix with solve function

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse

I want to take the inverse of a matrix `i.p` with the `solve` function. This `i.p` matrix is the result of an identity matrix subtracting `p`. 
Here's the code to get `i.p`:

```
p<-rbind(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,3), c(0,0,7,9,0,0,0), c(3,6,0,75,0,0,0), c(0,0,20,0,1,35,34), c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0), c(0,0,10,1,0,0,27), c(0,3,31,2,0,0,0))
dev<-c(sum(0,0,0,0,0,0,3), sum(0,0,7,9,0,0,0), sum(3,6,0,75,0,0,0), sum(0,0,20,0,1,35,34), sum(0,0,1,0,0,0,0), sum(0,0,10,1,0,0,27), sum(0,3,31,2,0,0,0))
p<-p/dev
p[7,]<-c(0,3,31,2,0,0,0)/sum(0,3,31,2,0,0,0, 30)
i<-diag(1, 7, 7)    #make a 7X7 identity matrix
i.p<-i-p         #identity matrix substract probability matrix  I-P
i.p.s<-solve(i.p, i)   #inverse of I-P
```

Here's the `p`, `i.p`, and `i.p.s` matrices:

[image: screenshot showing p, i.p, i.p.s matrix]

This inverse `i.p.s` multiplies the matrix `i.p` should be an identity matrix.

```
i.p %*% i.p.s
```

However this multiple calculated with the code above was clearly not an identity matrix. Why is that?

[image: The multiple of i.p and its inverse, i.p.s]

Comment: The result is an identity matrix. All the values off the diag is almost 0.

Comment: it is almost the identity.... floating point errors

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal. Try `all.equal(i.p %*% i.p.s, diag(7))`

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: @Jaap the question did give a reproducible example ... the images just show the results of the code that they supplied

Comment: @user20650 oops, sorry! on the other hand: if you can give a reproducible example, it isn't too hard i guess to include just the text output instead of a picture (which is better imo and also less cumbersome)

Comment: ha, no prob, and yup i do agree.... just thought id mention it as sometimes it can attract downvotes for the poor op - which i think is a bit unnecessary for a new user, esp in this case,